# Using textures in wpf 3D

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, 3d

I got a question about using textures in WPF on 3D models. this is my first time in WPF 3D.

It did succeed doing it (kinda) the same way for the floor plane. It works to get the texture on the model that represent the 4 outside walls but its completly streched and/or it's displayed crooked as seen on the following image.

[image: Texture problem]

I think the problem is that the model has more then 4 points, It has 8 to be exact and 4 planes constructed out of 2 triangles each.

I dont really know what I'm doing wrong. It probably has something to do with the texture coordinates but I cant figure out what. Already tried some other values on the texture coordinates but that did not help much.

It would be great if someone could help me figure this out or atleast point me in the right direction.

my XAML code of the model:

```
<GeometryModel3D>
    <GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
        <MeshGeometry3D Positions="20,0,0 20,0,3 20,20,3 20,20,0 0,20,3 0,0,0  0,20,0 0,0,3"
        TriangleIndices="0 1 2 3 0 2    4 5 6 4 7 5    0 5 1 1 5 7   6 3 4 4 3 2"
        TextureCoordinates="0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1    0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1    0,1 0,1 1,0 1,1   0,0 0,1 1,0 1,1"/>
     </GeometryModel3D.Geometry>
     <GeometryModel3D.Material>
         <DiffuseMaterial>
             <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
                 <ImageBrush ImageSource="pack://siteoforigin:,,,/images/brick.jpg" />
             </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
         </DiffuseMaterial>
      </GeometryModel3D.Material>
         <GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
         <DiffuseMaterial>
            <DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
               <SolidColorBrush Color="Blue"/>
            </DiffuseMaterial.Brush>
         </DiffuseMaterial>
      </GeometryModel3D.BackMaterial>
 </GeometryModel3D>
```

Comment: Try to isolate an offending triangle. This is way to much investigation for us and you can do it yourself.

Comment: correct me if I'm wrong, it's just a problem with the order of the texture coordinates?

Comment: @user2543697 that's what I thought, the vertices look ok

Comment: Ok then I'm going to keep playing with the texture coordinates. I'm pretty new to this so it's not easy to find the origin of my mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed it myself. Instead of re-using the same point for multiple vertices, I re-created the point. Now I have a few more points but it works to put the texture decent on every rectangle.

example how i used to do it:

```
points: 0,0,0    0,0,1    1,0,0    1,0,1      0,1,0     0,1,1

indices: 0 2 1   2 3 1   0 1 4   1 4 3

texture coordinates: 0,1 0,0 1,1 1,0 1,1 1,0

example how i fixed:

points: 0,0,0    0,0,1    1,0,0    1,0,1    0,0,0    0,0,1    0,1,0     0,1,1

indices: 0 2 1   2 3 1    4 5 6   7 6 4

texture coordinates: 0,1 0,0 1,1 1,0    1,1 1,0  0,1 0,0
```

this isnt probably the most efficient/best sollution but it is a solution and it worked for me.